# Assign custom object into Object type variable in SSIS

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm writing SSIS that scans a SQL table, create an object from each record values and need to move it next to other SSIS flow elements.

I created object type variable (MyObject) and script task.
In my script task I wrote the next code:

```
RequestObject reqObj = new RequestObject();
reqObj.building = Dts.Variables["reqObj_Building"].Value.ToString();
reqObj.ID = Convert.ToInt32(Dts.Variables["reqObj_DeviceID"].Value);
//...
```

Now I tried to write the next code in order to assin `reqObj` into `myObject`.

```
Dts.Variables["myObject"].Value = new RequestObject();
Dts.Variables["myObject"].Value = reqObj;
```

but those lines throws the next run time exception :

```
Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsRuntimeException: The element cannot be found in a collection. This error happens when you try to retrieve an element from a collection on a container during execution of the package and the element is not there.
 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xC0010009): The element cannot be found in a collection. This error happens when you try to retrieve an element from a collection on a container during execution of the package and the element is not there.

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSVariables100.get_Item(Object Index)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables.get_Item(Object index)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables.get_Item(Object index)
   at ST_a3e0b574a8964ffb8af6f9fee31d5afd.csproj.ScriptMain.Main()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at System.Type.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
```

How can I assign custom object into SSIS Object type variable ?
It it possible?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not much of a C# expert, but in my opinion when it comes to objects you can't assign `value = object`.

Comment: Its not matter of opinion :-).
Try to put the next code in your VS:
            TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan();
            object aa;
            aa = t;
It works without a problem...

Comment: exactly, so assign object to object, not value to object. `Dts.Variables["myObject"] = reqObj`

Comment: I understand what you trying to say - i already tried this direction - it doesn't compile: "Error 1 Property or indexer 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables.this[object]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only 
". In myObject properties I set "ReadOnly" property to false

Comment: Use the Add method for the variables. Check this out:http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.variables.add.aspx

Comment: @Ofir, the reason you are getting that Read only error is because on the Script Screen of the Script Task Editor you probably put your SSIS variable in the ReadyOnlyVariables textbox instead of the ReadWriteVariables textbox.

Comment: @ jymbo I double checked it. Its not the problem in my case. my variable appear under ReadWriteVariables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so I'm adding an answer instead. I did the below steps to try and replicate your problem:

1. Created a new script task
2. Created a new class in the namespace of that script
3. Created a variable of type Object and added to script task as Read/Write variable
4. Initialised the new class and assigned that value to the Object variable.

Below is my code which ran successfully. Can you please explain if there is any thing I am missing/understanding wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ST_8eab6a8fbc79431c8c9eb80339c09d1d.csproj
{
public class myclass
{
    int a, b;

    public myclass()
    {
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
    }
}

[System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
{
    #region VSTA generated code
    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
    #endregion

    public void Main()
    {
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        myclass m = new myclass();
        Dts.Variables["myObject"].Value = m;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: it seems identical to what I did. I will be able to check it just on Sunday - I'll update here. Thanks